# Como fazer livereload usando Grunt para arquivos .less?

Tags: grunt, less

`A SOLUÇÃO ESTÁ NA TERCEIRA PARTE JUNTO COM OS ARQUIVOS.`

Consigo faze-lo para arquivos .htlm e .css mas não .less.

[Aqui](https://gist.github.com/feliupe/b3e256ae0407555f0f4f) o Gruntfile completo. Abaixo, um trecho da parte que acho que interessa mais:

```
watch: {
    all: {
            files: ['**/*.html','**/*.less'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
        }
    }
},
```

O CSS contido no .less só é atualizado quando recarrego a página manualmente.  Adicionei `'**/*.less'` e imaginei que teria o mesmo efeito para esta extensão. Alguém sabe o que pode estar errado? Sei que existe *target* less, mas queria entender porque o que fiz não funciona.

============

Adicionei a task `less` e utilizei `npm install grunt-contrib-less --save-dev` para instalar o plugin, mas ainda estou tendo problemas. Ao alterar o arquivo .less: o terminal atesta a alteração, mas surgem problemas de `NameError` e `@import` na pastas `/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/test/less`, que impedem a compilação -- aparentemente justificados, por se tratar de uma pasta de testes. Obrigado pela ajuda. Alguma outra luz @luciorubeens?

============

Consegui. Apenas deletei a pasta `/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/test` e os erros pararam de ser atestados.

Na task `less` o caminho dos arquivos `.less` não estava bem especificado. Ficou assim:

```
less: {
    development: {
       options: { compress: true },
       files: { 'saida.css': '/pastaOndeEstãoOsArquivos/*.less' }
    }
},
```

Abaixo os arquivos atualizados - com algumas outras funcionalidades úteis:

Gruntfile: https://gist.github.com/feliupe/309cc7adf28adefb682c

package: https://gist.github.com/feliupe/91010be2a1d085af64ca

Comment: Poste a solução como resposta, e não como parte da pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione as `tasks` que o Grunt terá que executar após esses arquivos serem modificados.

Utilize o plugin [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) para converter o código `less` em `css`.

```
less: {
    development: {
       options: { compress: true},
       files: { 'saida.css': '**/*.less' }
    }
},

watch: {
   all: {
      files: ['**/*.html','**/*.less'],
      tasks: ['less'],
      options: {
          livereload: true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ainda não consegui @luciorubeens. Editei a pergunta para refletir as alterações. Tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Rode a tarefa individualmente, no terminal `grunt less` e posta aqui a saída. @feliupe

Comment: Certifique-se de carregar o plugin, dessa forma: `loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-NOMEPLUGIN')`, pois vc apenas registrou a tarefa `server` (`registerTask`). Veja um [exemplo](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) da configuração. @feliupe

Comment: Os plugins já estavam sendo carregados aqui `require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);`. O problema foi resolvido - veja na resposta original. Obrigado!